# Switching between fstream trunc and app modes by variable

Tags: c++, append, truncate, ofstream

I found several associated threads, but none had a clear, complete solution to this task.

I need to choose the openmode of my ofstream during runtime in console and I don't quite understand the flow of the declarations necessary. I need some combination of things like:

```
std::ios_base::openmode myopenmode;
std::ios::openmode myopenmode;
std::ofstream::openmode myopenmode;
myopenmode = trunc; //??? or something.
```

And be able to set the value of myopenmode to trunc or app, however the syntax for that goes so eventually I have something like this:

```
myfilestream.open(filename, myopenmode);
```

I was just unable to find this in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I worked it out. Kind of obvious once I did it.

```
std::ofstream::openmode myopenmode = std::ofstream::trunc; // set to trunc
std::ofstream::openmode myopenmode = std::ofstream::app; // set to app
myfilestream.open(filename, myopenmode);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in open is a bitmask
see

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/openmode/

I'd say when you take in input either just get it as the proper bitmask or convert your input to the proper bitmask with if/else or switch statements.

Comment: Could you edit your answer with an example of what code accomplishes what you are saying?